# Tomcat Servlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I created simple servlet.

```
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("TEST");
        out.close();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

web.xml configuration

```
<servlet>
       <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>servlets.testServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

startup log

```
cmd /c ""D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\java" -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Administrator\.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\_WebApplication "-Dcatalina.home=D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp" -cp "D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start"
13 квіт 2011 23:35:47 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2\bin\..\.\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;D:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;D:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v3.2\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;d:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea 10.0.2\jre\jre\bin
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 565 ms
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml from C:\Users\Administrator\.IntelliJIdea10\system\tomcat\_WebApplication\conf\Catalina\localhost
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet testServlet as unavailable
13 квіт 2011 23:35:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException: servlets.testServlet**
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why is there a mistake?

Comment: Is your servlet in the classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have this file:

> webapps/WEB-INF/classes/servlets/testServlet.class

That said, please name your classes with pascal case instead of camel case - `TestServlet`

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA. I badly configured deploy. See screen.

Comment: My artifact settings
![artifact settings][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/kCRcO.png

Comment: @BILL and how does your servlet look like?

Comment: I believe that camel case is what they have (it's when you start with a lowercase letter and capitalize each internal word ... so all the camel "humps" are in the inside of the word).

But you're comment is correct that class names should be capitalized by convention.  :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Every time you create or edit an existing servlet, you should export the .war file back to WebApps folder.
2. Make sure the servlet classes created need not be under /WEB-INF/CLASSES, but should be created under a package.
3. Make sure the .jsp file which is using this servlet class is being referenced in xxxx.jsp in web.xml file.